# check if mapView has finished rendering?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview

So I know swift has `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap(_:fullyRendered:)`, but I have no clue how I can use that function to only add my mapView onto the view hierarchy when it finishes rendering.

Right now, even with the `DispatchGroup` `.enter()` and `.leave()`, the `view.addSubview(mapView)` is getting called before it finishes rendering, which results in my `MKPolylines` not showing up on the map when it loads.

How can I make sure that the map finishes rendering before `view.addSubview(mapView)` is called?

@Koen basically what my `viedDidLoad()` is doing:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView = MKMapView()

    let leftMargin:CGFloat = 0
    let topMargin:CGFloat = 0
    let mapWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.size.width
    let mapHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.size.height

    mapView?.frame = CGRect(x: leftMargin, y: topMargin, width: mapWidth, height: mapHeight)

    mapView?.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    mapView?.isZoomEnabled = true
    mapView?.isScrollEnabled = true

    mapView?.delegate = self
    mapView?.showsScale = true

    // I have this to make sure they run in order only after the previous block is finished because of dependencies
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // gets the routes as polylines and adds to mapView
        self.fetchRoutes()
        group.leave()
    }
    goup.notify(queue: .main) {
        group.enter()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // depending on the route data, adds the stops as annotations to mapView
            self.fetchAnnotations()
            group.leave()
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            // the idea was that once both route and stops are added to the mapView, display mapView to screen
            self.view.addSubview(mapView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the frame for your view so that it is initially off-screen. Once it is done rendering, change the frame to the correct value.

Comment: @Koen I know there are a few way to handle the mapView to show up, but my issue is how can I detect when the map finishes rendering? Couldn't find how mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap is supposed to be called

Comment: You don't call it yourself, it is a `MKMapViewDelegate` method, and you can act upon it as the delegate (usually the view controller). So, make the view controller the delegate of your `mkmapview` (eg in `viewDidLoad`), and then implement `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap` in your view controller.

Comment: @Koen got it, so I moved `self.view.addSubview(mapView)` to `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap` (the idea is to only load the mapView into the view when it finishes rendering), but the mapView doesn't show up on the screen even with `setNeedsDisplay()`. Same result with frame changing method.

Comment: I wouldn't use `addSubview` outside of `viewDidLoad`. Where do you create mapView? Please share some code of what you have tried.

Comment: @Koen added code

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by moving all of my data fetching code into a single function and using `DispatchGroup` to only call `addSubview(mapView)` after the fetching finishes.

Was not able to find out the root cause, but the issue was solved.